# Add row to Firebird query result using select

Tags: sql, firebird

Is it possible to extend query results with literals like this?

```
SELECT  name, city, age
FROM    users
UNION
SELECT  'John' as name, 'Amsterdam' as city, 20 as age
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from` clause is mandatory in Firebird, so write `from rdb$database`.

`rdb$database` is a system table that has only a single row.

Comment: Also, you may need `union all` instead of `union`, if you really want one row to be added. `as name` aliases are not mandatory, just keep the order of columns.

Comment: You may want to clarify that `rdb$database` is a system table that has only a single row.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks added. Initial answer was from a mobile phone, in late night, short and problem-solver  :)